# How to add native emoticons in php chat?

Tags: php, chat, emoji

How can i add native emoji here?
Because my php chat wont recognize them:
In chat box when i send an emoji i get this: ????

```
        $mod_text = preg_replace( '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,8}(\/*\S*)/' , "<span class=\"link-object\"><a class=\"dont-react\" href=\"$0\" target=\"_blank\">$0</a></span>" , escaper_html( $chat['text'] ) );



$array = array(
        'id' => $chat['id'],
        'time' => $chat['sendtime'],
        'img' => $chat['img_medium'],
        'img_big' => $chat['img_big'],
        'text' => $mod_text,
        'sticker' => $chat['sticker']?true:false,
        'sticker_format' => $chat['sticker']?get_sticker_pack( $chat['sticker_pack'] )['format']:'',
        'sticker_pack' => $chat['sticker_pack'],
        'sticker_index' => $chat['sticker_index']
    );
```

Comment: Did you set the right character set?

Comment: @DarkBee my database is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

Comment: What about the encoding of your files and the used character set inside html

Comment: @DarkBee i don't know how to do that,can you send a link with an example?

Comment: Can i add character set in .htaccess ?

Comment: [html utf-8](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp), as for the files it depends which IDE you are using. But you need to do `save as UTF-8 w/out BOM`

Comment: @DarkBee my chat reconize just those https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp